# Python Metaprogramming of Descriptors: How to add descriptor after class definition?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, descriptor

How do I associate a descriptor after a class has already been defined?

In a normal descriptor scenario I would just do this:

```
class X:
    d = Descriptor()
```

and then whenever `Descriptor.__get__(self,obj,kls)` is called, the second parameter is an instance of `X` and all is happy and wonderful.

But what if `X` is already defined like so:

```
class X: pass
```

How do I then add a descriptor after the fact (and have it function properly!)?  All my attempts are not getting proper association to the class

I'm doing this cuz I have a bunch of attributes I want to add in a DRY manner, and I want them to be cached_properties (a descriptor I'm using to memoize the values for each of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X.d = Descriptor()
```

That's all you need.